# Avro reflect: Serialization fails when property is of type Map<String, Map<>>

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, avro

I'm using the avro-reflect library to generate my avro-schemas. Currently I'm trying to de/serialize an object based on a class with a single property:

```
class Test {
 @Nullable
 @AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":[\"null\", {\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":[\"null\", \"string\"]}]}")
java.util.Map<String, java.util.Map<Locale, String>> test;

 ....

}
```

Because the value of the Map is of type Map too, I had to define my schema manually using the @AvroSchema annotation.
Now when I try to serialize and deserialize an object where test = null I get the error message: "Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.size()" because "map" is null".

Syntactically the schema seems fine. Maybe I missed something. Any idea how to solve the error?